# What is going on with these pistons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was messing around with pistons today, and I cam across this weird senario whhere they are not working as expected.  I took some screenshots, they are [Here](http://tyr42.imgur.com/pistons_not_working) and are in order.

I have three pistons on top of each other (A, B and C) with A on top.
I have a redstone repeater aiming at a wood block that is next to A

```
.RXA
XXXB
XXXC
```

Where X is wood, . is wire and R is a redstone repeater.

- Starting from off, if I turn power on at A, only A goes out.
- If I then turn on power to C, B and C go out.
- If I remove power to C, only C retracts.
- Once I remove power to A, A and B retract.

If I toggle power the other way:

- If I turn power on to C, then C goes out.
- If I turn power on to A, only A goes out, not B.
- If I remove power to C, then C goes in and B goes out.  This is madness.
- If I remove power to A then A and B retract.

This is really odd behavior.  Can someone explain the logic behind it so I can work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a known <s>glitch</s> <s>feature</s> behaviour.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/ifzhk/piston_glitch_if_a_piston_is_extended_the_piston/) It may or may not be  by design. [thisismyfirstpost](http://www.reddit.com/user/thisismyfirstpost) can only come up with this exchange as evidence:

> **jakpo8:** @jeb_ Can a piston push another piston? [#](http://twitter.com/#!/jakpo8/status/80250577640108032)
>   **jeb_:** @jakpo8 Only when the other piston is contracted [#](http://twitter.com/#!/jeb_/status/80253274636300288)

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, all the pistons are facing to the left.  No piston is pushing another piston.

Comment: Oh, I see that has been adressed.

Comment: That link is genius. I now know why my elevator won't work!